# How to get the expected value of #function or #line?

Tags: swift

I have a function that contains `#function` and `#line` that returns a string:

```
func exportMessage(content: String) -> String {
    if let fileURL = URL(string: #file) {
        return "\(fileURL.lastPathComponent): \(#function) - Line: \(#line)\n\(content)"
    }
    
    return "\(#function) - Line: \(#line)\n\(content)"
}
```

When trying to use `exportMessage` above function in another function:

```
func doSomething() {
    let result = exportMessage(content: "instance is nil")
    print(result)
}
```

The output is:

> MyPlayground.playground: exportMessage(content:) - Line: 5
>
> instance is nil

It contains "exportMessage" but *not* "doSomething" as the name of the function (`#function`). It is the same for the line number, it is line number in `exportMessage()` but *not* in `doSomething()`.

My expectation is to get the function name and the line number for  `doSomething()`, as:

> MyPlayground.playground: doSomething() - Line: 12
>
> instance is nil

Since I am aiming to use `exportMessage` in many functions, I'd assume that it should refers to the caller function. Is it achievable? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're proposing wouldn't really make sense, because it wouldn't be clear "which caller should it print"? Why `doSomething`? Why not the caller of `doSomething`? Or the caller of the caller? Ultimately, if this is how `#function` and friends behaved, it would only ever print `start` from `libdyld.dylid`.

To achieve the behaviour you want, you have to manually pull in the `#function` and `#line` values from the parent context:

```
func exportMessage(
    content: String,
    callingFunction: String = #function,
    callingLine: Int = #line
) -> String {
    if let fileURL = URL(string: callingFunction) {
        return "\(fileURL.lastPathComponent): \(callingFunction) - Line: \(callingLine)\n\(content)"
    }

    return "\(callingFunction) - Line: \(callingLine)\n\(content)"
}

func doSomething() {
    let result = exportMessage(content: "instance is nil")
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: That's what I got when I checked such a method declaration: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541112-assert. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `#function` and `#line` as default values in the method. Default values are evaluated at the point of call.

```
func exportMessage(content: String, file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line) -> String {
    if let fileURL = URL(string: file) {
        return "\(fileURL.lastPathComponent): \(function) - Line: \(line)\n\(content)"
    }

    return "\(function) - Line: \(line)\n\(content)"
}
```